# pyspark: merge (outer-join) two data frames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two data frames:

```
DF1:

    Id | field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D
     1 |   cat   |  12     |   black | 11
     2 |   dog   | 128     |   white | 19
     3 |   dog   |  35     |  yellow | 20
     4 |   dog   |  21     |   brown |  4
     5 |  bird   |  10     |    blue |  7
     6 |   cow   |  99     |   brown | 34
```

and

```
DF2:

    Id | field_B | field_C | field_D | field_E
     3 |  35     |  yellow | 20      |   123   
     5 |  10     |    blue |  7      |   454   
     6 |  99     |   brown | 34      |   398
```

And I am hoping to get the new_DF as

```
    Id | field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D | field_E
     1 |   cat   |  12     |   black | 11      |
     2 |   dog   | 128     |   white | 19      |
     3 |   dog   |  35     |  yellow | 20      |  123
     4 |   dog   |  21     |   brown |  4      |  
     5 |  bird   |  10     |    blue |  7      |  454
     6 |   cow   |  99     |   brown | 34      |  398
```

---

Could this be achieved by data frame operations? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this:

```
new_df = df1.join(df2, on=['field_B', 'field_C', 'field_D'], how='left_outer')
```

Comment: What will the code look if you need to join on ID and select either A or B field from either DF1 for DF2?